Git log comparing 2 branches doesn't give all the merges
I am using below command to compare the differences between 2 branches
git log origin/main..origin/develop --first-parent --merges --pretty=format:"%<(20,trunc)%an %C(white)%<(15)%ar%Creset %s %b"

This works perfect most of the time but sometimes misses some of the commits/branches merged into develop branch. I was wondering why? Usually the sub branches are created from develop and once work is done the changes are merged into develop and then develop changes are merged into main. The UI correctly shows all the merges but the above script misses some of the commits. Please let me know what additional information you need to troubleshoot this issue.

You are using --first-parent which is going to avoid many commits outside of the straight line coming from going through first parents of commits from develop. Is there a commit you think that should be displayed and that is reachable by going over first parents?

So I was running the command on my local but didn't do a git pull/fetch before running so the commits I was missing were from last few days. Once I did that the above command worked perfectly. Thanks.

I guess you could write your own answer, in case anybody Is facing the same question
